# Keep CakePHP Session after browser is closed

Tags: php, session, cakephp-1.3

How to keep CakePHP 1.3 session after browser is closed?

Answer (score 2):

Seems there are ways to increase the time for the session to live on through an overridden configuration value. (At the PHP level -- via [CakePHP Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1310/Sessions)). Using the code below you could change 0 to the number of seconds you'd like the session to live on for.

```
// Cookie is now destroyed when browser is closed, doesn't
// persist for days as it does by default for security
// low and medium
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
```

Example for 2 weeks:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 14);
```

The above code snippet would be written to a configuration file that you create in `app/config`. To get CakePHP to read that file on initialization add the following to `app/config/core.php`

```
Configure::write('Session.save','my_session');
```

Where `my_session` is the name of your configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to transform it into a cookie, as sessions are automatically removed when the browser is closed. See [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/180/Using-the-Component).

Comment: See this http://www.captain.at/howto-php-sessions.php. Sessions are destroyed once the browser is closed, no matter how long the expiry is set. That makes it different from cookies. Correct me if I am wrong again, and cite your source.

Comment: Yes, what Skaty says is the way to go. You need to convert the session data into cookie data.

Comment: Technically it _is_ a cookie already. It's just discarded when the browser window is closed because the cookie's lifetime is 0 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Set [`$this->Session->cookieLifeTime = $timeToLive;`](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/cake-session/#line-101), where `$timeToLive` is the length in seconds you would like the session to last. This is the total length, so if the browser window closes it will not be deleted, but note that it is *not* measured from the time the browser closed.

Comment: I'd have to say that this is probably the easiest to implement. Props, michaelc. That doesn't mean I think that a link to the source is "documentation." The fact is that CakePHP's docs don't list public properties for the session class and that is unfortunate.

Comment: @sholsinger - it's a docblock, so the API reference probably has it too; I prefer the source code. Also, CakePHP has a standard policy about documentation - if you didn't find it documented, add it :).

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is not destroyed when browser is closed.